# Using "gets" for user input

Tags: ruby

I currently have this code:

```
def main()

    info = []
    CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
        info.push(row)
    end

    headers = info.shift

    param = ARGV[0]
    if param.downcase == "action1"
        ans = func1(info, headers)
    elsif param.downcase == "action2"
        puts "Enter a value:\n"
        extra_param = gets.chomp
        p func2(info, headers, extra_param)
    else
        puts "Invalid Parameter"
    end

end
```

When I try to run this (with 'action2' as a command line argument), I get an error that says:

```
:in `gets': No such file or directory - action2 (Errno::ENOENT)
```

From what I have gathered, it seems that the "gets" in this case is not waiting for user input but trying to use the command line argument that I passed in to open/read a file. How do I make it so that the "gets" will instead wait for user input and disregard the command line argument?

Comment: If `param == "action1"` means that you're not getting to the `gets`, right?

Comment: Woops, I meant action2. Let me fix that. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `param = ARGV[0]`, do `param = ARGV.shift` to remove the argument from `ARGV`.  Otherwise, use `$stdin.gets` if you don't want to worry about `ARGV` having any input.

`Kernel#gets` will read from `ARGV`, so if you have passed any arguments without flushing them, you'll get the above error, since it's trying to read from a file named as the argument.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using STDIN.gets, is that any different from $stdin.gets?

Comment: `STDIN == $stdin # => true`